# Facebook extract Friends count of a user with BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, facebook, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the friends count field from my facebook user page:
facebook.com/someuser/friends

if I inspect the friends count element under "all Friends", it looks like this:17

so the span element with class _3d0 has the friends count, however, I am not able to extract this with BeautifulSoup... my settings are public.
How can I do this? Or does there exist a better library for webscraping, especially for facebook?

friends_count = soup.find_all("span",{"class":"_3d0"})

What is the reason for the result to be empty?

similarly, I want to get the names of all friends in the friends list and extract them somehow... the friends names are under several div and span tags.. I have the same problem that I cannot extract the text from those... what's the reason for that?

Comment: what for do you want to get names of all friends? you´re not supposed to get those, if they did not authorize your app - and you would not be allowed to store any data you get without authorization - privacy and stuff. scraping is not allowed on facebook, you MUST use the graph api and you will only get friends who authorized your app with the /me/friends endpoint.

Comment: well, I want to basically make a list of all friends... how can I get those? If I authorize with the facebook API? is there a functionality in the facebook API to do that?

Comment: why? what is the use case?

Comment: it is very important to know what for you need the list, the answer depends on it ;) - facebook only allows to access the list for very specific reasons, else you will only get a list of those who authorized your app.

Comment: ok thanks, well I basically want to create a graph with the connection of the friends, and later want to get a collection of the postings from all my friends for better overview..

Comment: ok, there is no way to get the friends for that, i´m afraid.

Comment: so you think one cannot even create a friends-connection graph? weird..

Comment: i don´t just think, i KNOW ;) - you can only get data of users who authorized your app, for privacy reasons.

Comment: ok but is there really no way, like with reverse Engineering? or similar?

Comment: scraping is not allowed, so there is no way, no. users who did not authorize your app are none of your business.